# Solution for error "Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl, :java.io.IOException:ZIP entry size is too large"?

Tags: r, bigdata

I am trying to import a large excel dataset into R using the package openxlsx. This error is being shown upon trying to load the file.

Using XLConnect was giving another Java IOException error, so I moved to using openxlsx but then this error is cropping up.

```
install.packages("openxlsx", dependencies = TRUE)
library(openxlsx)
BERFile <- read.xlsx2("C:/Users/EE Guest/OneDrive/BER data analysis/BER   Dataset 2019.xlsx", 1, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Java is not getting enough memory to open the large xlsx file. You can try to increase the memory available to Java:

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1000m")
data <- read.xlsx(filepath)
```